# Duplicating Highchart in php file

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am having troubles duplicating some highcharts in a php file. I separate each highchart in its own .js file. Everything works just fine if I stick to just one chart. As soon as I try to include several of the same chart, then only the first one shows up.

Below is the first highcharts .js file:

```
$(function () {
 $('#chart2').highcharts({
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 75
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
subtitle: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: [{
    categories: []
}],
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    tickAmount: 11,
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
      }
}, { // Secondary yAxis
    gridLineWidth: '0',
    labels: {
        format : '{value}%',
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },

    opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
},
series: [{
    name: '',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 0,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },

}, {
    name: '',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  }]
 }, 

    function(theChart){
     var tableName = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>';
     $.getJSON("Data.php", {id: escape(tableName)}, function(json) {

     theChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(json[0]['data']); 
     theChart.series[0].setData(json[4]['data'], true);
     theChart.series[1].setData(json[3]['data'], true);

    });                               
 });

    var theChart = $('#chart2').highcharts();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

 });
```

Below is the second highcharts .js file. Note that they are exactly the same. The only thing that is changed is the variable names (I dont know what else to do). As I said before - both work just fine apart. But when I include both in my .php file, then only the first will show up.

```
$(function () {
 $('#chart3').highcharts({
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 75
},
title: {
    text: 'EBITDA and EBITDA-margin'
},
subtitle: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: [{
    categories: []
}],
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    tickAmount: 11,
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
        }
      }
}, { // Secondary yAxis
    gridLineWidth: '0',
    labels: {
        format : '{value}%',
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },

    opposite: true
}],
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
},
series: [{
    name: '',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 0,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },

}, {
    name: '',
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  }]
 }, 

    function(theChart1){
     var tableName1 = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>';
     $.getJSON("Data.php", {id: escape(tableName1)}, function(json) {

     theChart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(json[0]['data']); 
     theChart1.series[0].setData(json[4]['data'], true);
     theChart1.series[1].setData(json[3]['data'], true);

    });                               
 });

    var theChart1 = $('#chart3').highcharts();

 });
```

You will notice that I call the first chart 'chart2' and the second one 'chart3'. I think the problem is very strange since I only get this problem on this exact chart type (dual-axis column+line). The way I include the files in the .php file is by using php include in head part. I then call them in the body part by using div.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
         include('../index/charts2.js');
         include('../index/charts3.js');
    ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="chart2"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="chart3"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</body>
```

I hope somebody here will be able to help. Let me know if you need anything further to find out about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this can help you, look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/7cvCX/

it was taken from here [how do I get two highcharts on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078277/how-do-i-get-two-highcharts-on-one-page)
(all credit to the one that posted it)

```
no code nesesary, look at the fiddle, its self explanatory.
```

also, the console once you execute everything show some error?

also, are you shure that its just one that is showed?, is there a chance that the both charts are executed one on top of the other?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I have seen your jsfiddle example but I think the problem is within my .js files. Remember that I have many identical highcharts showing already. I have added some extra code to my question in order to show how i call them in the .php file - please check if you have the time. I think the problem is either within the two .js files or maybe the Data.php file that I use for getting the JSON data from. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just figured out the issue!!!! On the bottom of the .js file I had:     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); - I tried to remove this (don't know what it does anyway) and everything suddenly worked!!! Great succes.